# Google Cloud Endpoint Not Creating Api in Endpoint List

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend

i have checkout this project and follow all the commands and deployed it but no api is listed in google end point.

i am not able to find why its not working?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows that you have one API listed. Do you mean that it shows no data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the point to list our API we need to deploy swagger document. All Api listed in swagger will be visible in cloud endpoints.